# How to change val of select2 from id to name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, acts-as-taggable-on, select2-rails

I'm trying to fill rails form input filed using select2 gem. I'm also using acts-as-taggable-on gem on that field.

As data for select2, I'm using remote data from a database. This collection has two fields: id and name. It works fine, but when I submit the form, the id gets treated like a name. Example:

Let's say I select "milk". It's id is 5. Then "5" gets processed. The program looks for tag "5" in my tags, doesn't find it and creates new tag named "5" with a new id. How do I change this?

Comment: can you add the code you're referring to?

Comment: I actually worked it out. I was missing:
`id: function(data) { return data.name; }`